# How to upgrade pip package manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, module, pycharm

> ""Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement upgrade
>   (from versions: ) Not matching distribution found for upgrade You are
>   using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is availalbe. You
>   should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install -- upgrade
>   pip' command."

What should I do in this situation to solve this problem and update the pip module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to a terminal (pycharm has terminal in the lower pane) and run:

```
python -m pip install -- upgrade pip
```

BTW, pycharm version has nothing to do with pip version or even python version.

Edit: Finally it turned out that the wrong package was installed. see comments below.

Comment: write in the console "pip --version". what it shows?

Comment: From cmd :" 'pip--version' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file"

Comment: u missed a space between the pip and the --version

Comment: In terminal shows 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' when i type: 'python -m pip install -- upgrade pip'

Comment: in the same console run "python -m pip install --upgrade pip". What does it show?

Comment: But when I go to settings -> project interpreter, shows up to me on package list pip in 19.0.3 version

Comment: so where do u see the "pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is availalbe"?

Comment: In console I see pip 10.0.1v
But in Pycharm -> settings -> project interpreter i see package named pip in 19.03v

Now from console upgrade pip command:

"Collecting pip
Downloading http...
.
.
.
Uninstalling pip 10.0.1:
Successfully uninstalled pip - 10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-19.0.3
"

Comment: do u install it from the "settings -> project interpreter" right "+"?

Comment: You're right. I tried to do it through the console before myself, but it did not work out. 
Only now did I see the download and installation bar. But in project in Pycharm i still see error at the same place.

Comment: the pip message is not error it is usually just a warning. Please append to your original post the full error you see

Comment: "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:/Pythonprojekty/112(reverse_pair - module error).py", line 4, in <module>
    from inlist import in_bisect, make_word_list
ImportError: cannot import name 'in_bisect' from 'inlist' (X:\Pythonprojekty\venv\lib\site-packages\inlist.py)
"

Comment: if yo u open "X:\Pythonprojekty\venv\lib\site-packages\inlist.py" do u see the functions you are trying to import?

Comment: In "site-packages" folder I see folder named "inlist-1.0.1-py3.7.egg-info"

Comment: I checked again and was about to write that he is not there, but now I noticed that he is, sorry for the mistake.
So, yes there is file "inlist.py"

Comment: so does it have the function u try to import?

Comment: No, it have just each_item function. Nothing more

Comment: OK. I think I understand. There is a packahe called inlist but it is not the inlist you want to use. uninstall the inlist. and just copy the file to your folder from https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkPython2/blob/master/code/inlist.py

Comment: Everything works!
Thank you so much for your help and your time!

Answer (score 0):

Here it's the command to upgrade all packages installed in the pip.

```
pip list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

Please run this command and check, comment if any issue faces